# Mixing data types results in heart output

Tags: c, types, character, kr-c

I was fooling around with one of the sample programs in the K&R, and found that this

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%lf\n", nc );
    putchar(nc);
}
```

produces output that is 3.000000 (which I totally expected) then a new line with a heart on it (which I totally did not expect).  Why would it output a new line with a heart on it?
I assume it has something to do with me mixing data types.

Comment: I know why the new line - just interested in why the heart shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `putchar()` with a `double` as an argument.  It's going to get implicitly typecast to `int`, and then that character will be output.  You get the heart because for some reason your character set has a heart as character number 3.  If you run it and type a bunch more characters before the `EOF`, you'll get a different character.  On my machine, your program doesn't make a heart, but if I type more characters, I can get whatever I want on that next line.  ASCII character 3 is `ETX`, end of text, so I don't know why you would get the heart in your case - are you using some weird locale or character set?  What does this program output on your machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    putchar(3);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

You're getting the heart because that's what's in your character set at position 3.  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(symbol)#Computer_code):

> In Code page 437, the original character set of the IBM PC, the value of 3 (hexadecimal 03) represents the heart symbol. This value is shared with the non-printing ETX control character, which overrides it in many contexts.

Comment: That just makes a heart when I run it. :)

Comment: @Laura, yeah, that's expected.  I edited my answer with some more information.  Character 3 is a heart, and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks!  Learned a little more today :)